# Method return different type of var depending on the context

Tags: php, oop

Better than few words, what I want to do is :

1. Return string

   ```
   $obj->method();
   ```
2. In this case, I want `method()` to return an object

   ```
   $obj->method()->method2();
   ```

Is that possible?
And if possible, someone could help me please ?

Comment: A called method does not know in which context it was called. So it can not determine if it should return the result or itself.

Comment: You can pass a parameter to `method()` to tell it what to return.

Comment: Please, stop trying to add *magic* to your code. It's always a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `method()` method cannot know whether it will be used as a string or as an object. The only thing you can do that comes somewhat near your expectation would be to have it return an object with a `__toString()` method:

```
<?php

class YourObject {
    public function method2() {
        // ...
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return 'some string';
    }
}

?>
```

and have `$obj->method()` return an instance of this class. You can use that like a string (`echo $obj->method();`) as well as an object (`$obj->method->method2();`).

Comment: I guess that's one way to solve this problem.  Have it depend on how it's used after it's returned.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a simple boolean to the method to tell it what to return.